# Programmatic access to inline Styles where name is separated with dashes

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

[Here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Programmatic_access) is shown how to use styles in CamelCase, but how to use styles with a dash in its name? Valid Java method name can't have dashes in it (at least eclipse shows syntax error).

Style defined in template:

```
.menu-inactive{ background-color: grey; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CssResource.ClassName` for valid CSS class names that are invalid Java identifiers.

```
interface MyCssResource extends CssResource {
    @CssResource.ClassName("menu-inactive")
    String menuInactive();
}
```